# Start a process with shell function

Tags: .net, windows

I am using the [shell function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.shell%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to start an exe from a program under windows seven os.

the command:

```
RetVal = Shell(szProgram & szParameter, AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
```

The executable is randomly started: some time it start correctly some time not

The same scenario under windows xp os, the executable start correctly all the time.

In both cases the retVal ( process iD) is generated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume szParameter is one or more arguments passed to the program identified by szProgram. You are concatenating them with no intervening whitespace, so the shell is interpreting the whole thing as a file name, which is probably not what you intend.

Try:

```
RetVal = Shell(szProgram & " " & szParameter, AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
```